# load documents in generator for training

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have a set of folders which has the following structure

```
Data
  -->1
    --->_1.txt
    --->_2.txt
    --->_3.txt
  --->2
    --->_1.txt
    --->_2.txt
    --->_3.txt
```

1,2 are labels and every folder has some text documents. I am designing a text classification model using keras. I am loading all the data into memory at once.

```
 import sklearn.datasets as skds

 files_train = skds.load_files(path_train,load_content=False)
 # Read and add data from file to a list
 i=0
 for f in labelled_files:
       data_list.append(Path(f).read_text((encoding='utf8',errors='ignore')))
```

My corpus is huge with the size of 20 GB . How can I load this data efficiently into the memory for training

```
 history = self.model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=self.num_epochs,
                        verbose=1,
                        validation_split=0.1,
                        shuffle=True,
                        callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [fit_generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator) (potentially using multiple workers) rather than loading the dataset fully in memory. My advise would be for you to develop and test the generator independently of using it to train the model.